# Set permissions to MSI installer

Tags: import, permissions, wix, installation, registry

I have a program that imports `.reg` file to `registry` on button click.

The program imports as well as I run it from code, but when I create an MSI installer and run it, the .reg file does not get imported.

The reason is probably the permissions of the MSI installer.
How can I set full permissions to the installer, so that it could access and import to registry?

Answer (score 1):

Probably best if you make it a deferred Custom Action with Impersonate on No. (This means it will run elevated). But I have to warn you, running a .reg file is really not the way to go. Harvest the keys with Heat.exe for example.

Comment: Thanks, I do not want to import the reg file during installation (and use Heat.exe for it) I just want to perform the importing on button click. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You will need to create your own dialog and add it to your dialog sequence. Create a button on your new dialog and let it execute a custom action that will import the reg file and run the command.

Comment: Thanks, I mean a sialog not during the installation, just as part of the application itself. Possible?

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse. You probably need to set the correct permissions on the file and folders, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a security problem that forbids a program that sits in `Program Files`, to import files to registry.

Therefore, I create an `MSI` installer that asks the user where to install the program, and then the import is done without security limits.